# In Microsoft Ajax, what exactly does $find do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, microsoft-ajax

I'm so confused as to what $find from Microsoft Ajax actually is.
Does it just return a control in a similar manner that the $ operator from jquery  or javascript's own getElementById do?

If I do

```
$find('someControlId')
```

Will I get the same object back from jquery's

```
$('#someControlId')
```

or Javascript

```
getElementById('someControlId')
```

The reason I ask is because when I use $find on the ClientId of some Telerik controls, the object returned seems to have a type.

So is this just another instance of the wheel being reinvented or does it actually do something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to *find* the following information via a quick Google search:

> Why should you opt for $find instead of $get? The $get function
>   is shorthand for document.getElementById. As such, it can only look
>   for DOM elements. The $find function stands for Sys.Application.findComponent
>   and applies to any component of the Microsoft AJAX Library that has been
>   programmatically created.

From MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135984.aspx

For further reading, look at the [Sys.Applicationl.findComponent doco](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397522.aspx).