# Why $find doesn't work?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, webforms

This is my code:

```
// user control
<asp:CheckBox ID="chbGenerali" runat="server" />

// js
var prova = $find("chbGenerali");
console.log(prova.checked);
```

but I get `TypeError: prova is null`. It should be a sort of:

```
document.getElementById("<%=chbGenerali.ClientID%>")
```

isn't it?

Do I need to enable somethings

Comment: Look at the generated html code, that will help you see what the id is on the client side.

Comment: @OlliM: `ContentPlaceBody_Registrazione1_chbGenerali` yes it is the input type checkbox :O

Comment: According to this SO answer, $get() is shorthand for document.getElementById(), $find() is slightly different. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411056/in-microsoft-ajax-what-exactly-does-find-do

Comment: Already tried with `$get()`, I get the same TypeError

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ID's set compile time do not always equal the ID at runtime by default.

As you are using framework 4.0, you can use the `ClientIDMode` property on the control.

```
ClientIDMode="Static"
```

Read [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx) weblog article for more information about the ClientIDMode property.

Comment: I prefer this answer as it fixes the underlying issue rather than (skilfully) working around it.

Comment: @StephenKennedy: CLientIDMode is easier to apply, but you will have to ensure yourself the uniqueness of your control in the page. For example, if this code appears in an ascx file, and if two instance of the control exists, this will lead to error

Answer (score 4):

Basically, the client side ID is not the same as the server side, because of the control tree handling. ASP.Net generate client side which are the combination of the hierarchy of the control Id's. This will ensure uniqueness of Ids.

For example, if your control is in the panel "`pnlABC`", and your checkbox is named "`chkGenerali`", the output clientID will be "`pnkABC_chkGenerali`". Extend this logic to the whole control tree to get the actual ID.

The simpliest way to solve your issue is to replace your code by:

```
var prova = $find("<%= chbGenerali.ClientID%>");
```

which will generate the actual client side ID at render time.

Comment: This is indeed the better solution :)

Comment: @Aphelion: yours is also acceptable. If the control has a application wide behavior (exemple: unique search box in the header of all pages), it's perfectly acceptable to specify explicitely its ID by force the ClientIDMode. It actually depends on the usage of the control.